# Using Firefox with https and a self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, https, certificate

With FF39 I've got an issue with our firewall. After enabling deep content inspection, on  https websites there comes an error sec_error_untrusted_issuer.
The selfsigned cert from the firewall is imported to the browser.
Using IE10 don't show this problem on the same machine.
Can this be a bug in FF, or is it configuration error?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Regards

Catweazle30169

Comment: Must be a configuration error. Such setups work w/o problems for me with FF. Make sure to not only import the CA but mark it as trusted too.

Comment: Hello Steffen. The import of the cert is official way. But I will test it without the cert tommorrow...